# How can I put variables instead of literal numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, literals, substitution

I want to replace this line :

```
 polygon.setAttribute("points", "50,0 200,0 125,150");
```

it works with permanent numbers:

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/CCr5T/13/)

with this line:

```
polygon.setAttributeNS (null, "points", ("LeftWidth,0 RightWidth,0 RopTringleX,RopTringleY"));
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/CCr5T/14/)

How can I do that? Many thx.

The code:

```
function CreateSVG () {
            var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var boxWidth = 250;
            var boxHeight = 250;
            var LeftWidth=(250-boxHeight)/2;
            var RightWidth=250-LeftWidth;
            var RopTringleX=(RightWidth-(boxWidth/2));
            var RopTringleY=(boxHeight);


            var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
            svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
            svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "width", 250);
            svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "height", 250);
            svgElem.style.display = "block";

            var polygon = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "polygon");
            svgElem.appendChild (polygon);
alert(RopTringleY);        

            polygon.setAttributeNS (null, "points", ("LeftWidth,0 RightWidth,0 RopTringleX,RopTringleY"));

            var path = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "path");
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke', "white");
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke-width', 4);
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'fill', "yellow");
            polygon.appendChild (path);

            var svgContainer = document.getElementById ("svgTriangle");

            svgContainer.appendChild (svgElem); 
            alert(boxWidth + ' ' + boxHeight);     
        }
CreateSVG ();
​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
polygon.setAttribute("points", LeftWidth + ",0 " + RightWidth + ",0 " + RopTringleX + "," + RopTringleY);
```